# Terminating or halting based on value from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php script with a an image that when you click on it you are redirected to another page.

I also have an ajax / jquery check to see if you are logged in or not.

So, when someone clicks on the link, ajax finds out if they are logged in, and if not they get an alert box.

My link has the id='newlisting'

```
$("#newlisting").click( function() {
      $.post("ajaxqueries.php", {"checkloggedin": ''}, function(data) {
         var loggedin = data;
         if ( loggedin == 0 ) {
            alert('Please login or register to use this feature');
         }
      });
   });
```

The problem is that when they click on on the alert box, it continues to the screen as if you were logged in.

I need the php script to exit if they get the alert box and hit ok.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `preventDefault()` to prevent "normal" link behavior first. Then, you'll be able to console.log the `data` returned by Ajax to check if it fits your condition.

Comment: Another approach would be to set a session variable when user is logged in (on server side)... So in the page targeted by the link, you could check this variable and redirect to home if not. It yould be more "secure".

Comment: I agree with @LouysPatriceBessette. By moving it to the server, people can't modify your javascript to take themselves to the logged in page. Someone could even just copy and paste the link themselves into their browser.

Comment: This definitely would be better... I don't know the sensibility of the data to be protected by the login... But since there is an effort to hide it, security should be handled on server-side. No client-side JavaScript can "protect" unlogged in access, if nothing is done on server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the redirect.

```
$("#newlisting").click( function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.post("ajaxqueries.php", {"checkloggedin": ''}, function(data) {
         var loggedin = data;
         if ( loggedin == 0 ) {
            alert('Please login or register to use this feature');
         }else{
            // Redirect code goes here.
         }
      });
   });
```

Comment: I changed it to include the prevent default and that stops it from moving on.  But it also prevents the redirect if the user is logged in. I guess I could use the else statement for redirect but then I would need a script for multiple pages if i wanted to use the same code on various pages nor redirecting to the same location all the time.

Comment: Correct. You can add `window.location = event.target.href;` inside of your else block.